# Multiple IMongoClient in .NET core

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to figure out how I could work effectively with multiple IMongoClient's in .net core (2).
To be more specific, I have a create package that needs a IMongoClient, while that MongoClient 'could' be shared with the whole application, I'm trying to find a way to allow it to specify a different one.

For now I have this:

```
# In startup
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(p => return new MongoClient(...));
services.AddMyPackage(...);

# Some service from my package
public Service(IMongoClient client)
{
...
}
```

However this now forces my application to 'share' this mongo client.

I would like to reach something like

```
# In startup

# app mongoclient
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(p => return new MongoClient(...));

# package mongoclient (could be a different interface ...)
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>(p => return new MongoClient(...));

services.AddMyPackage(p => /*Specify the mongoclient to use here*/);
```

At first I tried the following, in the package create the following interface:

```
public interface IPackageMongoClient : IMongoClient
{}
```

And use `IPackageMongoClient` for DI internally.

However you cannot do the following:

```
services.AddSingleton<IPackageMongoClient>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IMongoClient>());
```

So to recap: I would like to be able to specify which client to use when 'adding' the package.

There must be some trick I am not seeing

Comment: https://blog.rsuter.com/dotnet-dependency-injection-way-to-work-around-missing-named-registrations/